# How to normalize an image color?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, machine-learning, face-detection, adaboost

In their paper describing [Viola-Jones object detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework) framework (Robust Real-Time Face Detection by Viola and Jones), it is said:

> All example sub-windows used for training were variance normalized to
>   minimize the effect of different lighting conditions.

**My question is** "What kind of tool did they use to normalize the images?"

I'm NOT looking for the specific tool that Viola & Jones used but a similar one that produces almost the same output. I've been following a lot of haar-training tutorials(trying to detect a hand) but not yet able to output a good detector(xml).

I've tried contacting the authors, but still no response yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way is to apply plain and simple normalization assuming normal distribution to all elements.

First find the average (Mu) and [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Sample_standard_deviation) (S):

```
Mu = 1/N * Sum(a[i][j]) for each i,j 
S  =  sqrt(1/(N-1) *  Sum((a[i][j] - Mu)^2)) for each i,j
       (in here N is the number of pixels, 20*20 in the viola jones case)
```

From this, we can normalize the value of each pixel using standard normal distribution formula (by [standardizing all values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standardizing_normal_random_variables)):

```
a'[i][j] = (a[i][j] - Mu) / S
```

---

Another method is [vector normalization](http://www.fundza.com/vectors/normalize/index.html), which basically says:

- Find the *length* of the vector: `|a| = sqrt(sum (a[i][j]*a[i][j])) for each i,j`
- Assign: `a'[i][j] = a[i][j] / |a|`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really helped me a lot! This method can be implemented in MATLAB right?

Comment: @KojiIkehara: Yes. Also, I believe it already is implemented in matlab. When I come back from work I can check how to implement it in octave (open source variant of matlab) if you want (it will be only much later today)

Comment: Yes sure, that would be great! I'll research about it too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi! I've posted another question, I hope you can help me. :)

Comment: Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932327/how-to-normalize-an-image-using-octave